# Foreign key referencing a view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, foreign-keys

I'm attempting to reference a view with a foreign key but I am getting this error:

"Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

However, I have created a primary key on this view and verified it in the Constraints tab in TOAD.

This is the table I'm attempting to create:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION
(   
    QUESTION_ID             INTEGER not null,
    CREATED_USER_ID         INTEGER not null,    
    CONSTRAINT PK_QUESTION  PRIMARY KEY (QUESTION_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_USER
        FOREIGN KEY (CREATED_USER_ID)
        REFERENCES SOME_VIEW(VIEW_ID)
);
```

SOME_VIEW is a view based on another view which points to the employee table in another schema.

Comment: I gather you want/need this in order to have a single foreign key that could be from multiple tables, because a column can have multiple foreign key constraints against a single column... but the value in the column would have to exist in all the foreign constraint related tables.  I hope this is a means of transitioning the database, and only temporary.

Comment: In other words, SOME_VIEW, OTHER_VIEW and BASE_TABLE will all have to have the same values in order for this foreign key constraint to work?

Comment: Related, though old (2006): http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2006/11/view-constraints.html

Comment: @echoblaze: If you were to add foreign constraints on OTHER_VIEW to both SOME_VIEW and BASE_TABLE (move names around as you like), yes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I don't have that rights on the employee tables (which was the point of using the view); I read your link and apparently materialized views might be the solution - do you know much about this? I'm going to read more about it in the meantime

Comment: @echoblaze: Materialized views are notoriously finicky; check that you can actually create one before considering referential integrity.  I would really press for rights on the table you need to use, or consider pulling the employee records into a local table periodically (that's all a materialized view is, effectively).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regardless the possibility of creating foreign keys to views, it is indeed not the best idea to implement.

Database views were designed to let user comfortably query some data he needs, but at the same time to serve as a security barrier, to conceal all database structure, including tables, data constraints in tables, and, yes, also table cross-references.

So, a good practice to me would be to reference an existing table from a your new one, despite its residence in other scheme.

Comment: alright, thanks for all the feedback. we've decided to do joins on the application level rather than the database level

Comment: There is something called role-playing views in dimensional DWH modelling. In that case such kind of foreign key constraints it seems to be a good practice anyhow.

Comment: I'm not so sure I can totally agree. Imagine an _Departments_-table containing records that all have a _chief_ column. As one _chief_ can be responsible for multiple _departments_, I would created another table, _Chiefs_. As employees are likely to have a separation date, I would then add _entrydate_ and _separationdate_ columns to the _chiefs_-table, and refer the _department_ A,B and C to the _chief_ #2 **that is valid right now**. This would require row filtering, which I can achieve in a view like _currentchiefs_, which I would hook up to _departments_ instead of the source table _chiefs_.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to implement SOME_VIEW as a Materialized view, since you are pointing to another schema.
Then you can alter the materialized view to add a primary key and even refer to this view from a foreing key.

This is the documentation you should read:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm

Answer (score -2):

The foreign key against a view is probably what's causing the trouble.

Comment: Is it not possible to have a foreign key against a view?