# Assigning foreign and primary keys to view columns

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a view and wish to make one of its columns a foreign key. Is this possible? How?

Is it possible to make a view column a pprimary key? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I have a foreign key referencing a column in a view in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447122/can-i-have-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-column-in-a-view-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which SQL server you use.

- With MS SQL Server it is possible, if you use `with schemabinding` to create the view.

Comment: Sorry, the answer was not convenient, but the question did not mention what sql it is about. So there was no possible answer, since MSSQL, Oracle etc. are each different on this point. Still this is how to do it: `create view as ... with schemabinding`, after that you can create an index.

Comment: Thanks, I will research the use of schemabinding. It's new to me.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add constraints to views in MS SQL Server. If you look at the syntax for the [Create View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) statement it is quite clear. You can however [create indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) with a clustered index on it, but that's not really the same thing (although it can be useful).

Comment: That's what I thought but Lorenz's solution of using schemabinding sounds contradictory. I need to do more research, and trial-and-error. Thanks.

Comment: @gcarterIT In fact, I used schemabinding just fo create an indexed view. Even if you would use schemabinding, you could not do more than that. You can create a clustered index (= primary key), but I didn't try to use this key as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

what about making the column in the base table (that the view references) a foreign key.

but could you please elaborate on your problem, will you be updating data using the view? Is the view a complex query or is it simply a select from single table etc.

Comment: I will not be updating from the view. The view consists of a JOIN between 2 tables. The problem: I need a lookup table in Iron Speed, and if I understand the docs correctly, the base table and lookup table must refer to the same foreign key. My lookup table is a view , but has no foreign key; so I wish to assign it one that matches the base table.