# Is it possible to create read-only synonym in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, synonym

We have 2 different databases DB1 and DB2 with tables in DB2 referring to tables in DB1.

We are looking into the possibility of using SYNONYMS with read-only access in DB2 and use EntityFramework to refer to these SYNONYMS as tables in DB2.

Since currently EF doesn't span across multiple databases, after reading this article (http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/) we are one step ahead, but, we want to only have read-only access to the newly created SYNONYMS.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about a read-only view?

Comment: We have foreign keys etc., i don't think its a possibility.

Comment: What have foreign keys have to do with that? You can create a view from every `select`.

Comment: Hey @juergen thanks for your time and digging this deeper. You can't reference a view in a foreign key.
More on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447122/can-i-have-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-column-in-a-view-in-sql-server an SYNONYM will have the same behavior as the table itself while a view may not. Thats one of the reasons why we want a readonly SYNONYM such that  its behavior is maintained as is but just the access changes when as SYNONYM in a different DB ( in this case DB2 )

Answer (score 0):

You can create a schema for your synonym (such as "EntityFramework" or "EF" for simplicity). Create a role for your schema, naming it something to the tune of "EntityFrameworkUser".

Now there are two paths, here- this first one if you only ever have SELECT access, or the second one if you may also need EXECUTE access.

FIRST:

Going into the properties of your EntityFramework schema, you can navigate to Permissions, search for and add your EntityFrameworkUser role, and check only SELECT in the list of permissions below.

SECOND:

Going into the properties of your EntityFrameworkUser role, you can navigate to Securables, go to "Search..." for securables, use 'All objects belonging to the schema' with your EntityFramework schema.

For each of the objects showing up as a result, which should just be Synonyms (unless you also made new tables/SPs in the "EntityFramework" schema), you can grant access to "Select", and leave everything else unchecked unless you want the user to have more or less power with those objects.

REGARDLESS:

This will allow you to have visibility to the table without write/execute access. Assign whichever server user needs this readonly access, and add them to the "EntityFrameworkUser" role. In my case, there's a "WebApplication" and a "DesktopApplication" user, both of which are assigned to the "EntityFrameworkUser" role.

This should solve your issue of visiblity, while restricting write and execute access within the system.