# Foreign key reference tableA.column or tableB.column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Is it possible to have a foreign key (InnoDB) reference two possible tables?

If not, is there a workaround for this?

There are two different subjects that contain the same field (interface_id).  A third table references this field.

An example being:

```
physical_interface ( id, name, etc )
virtual_interface ( id, name, etc )
usage ( interface_id, etc )
```

I had an idea of using a view, but came across this related to SQL server: [Can I have a foreign key referencing a column in a view in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447122/can-i-have-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-column-in-a-view-in-sql-server) so it seems you cannot use views in foreign keys.

The alternative, I suppose, would be storing all intefaces in one table but I feel that would be less organized.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is interesting. MySQL 5.6.14, my version, won't stop you from creating a foreign key relationship with 2 tables but that is a bad idea. Let me show you why.

Create 2 master tables: test1 and test3

```
create table test1 (field1 int, primary key (field1));
create table test3 (field1 int, primary key (field1));
```

Create a dependent table that will have FK relationship with field1 of both tables.

```
create table test2 (
  field0 int, 
  field1 int, 
  constraint fk_test2_test1 
     foreign key (field1) 
     references test1 (field1), 
  constraint fk_test2_test3 
     foreign key (field1) 
     references test3 (field1)
);
```

Great. Now let's add some data and see the issue:

```
insert into test1 values (1);
insert into test3 values (3);
```

Master tables are done. Let's add data to dependent table.

```
insert into test2 values (100, 1);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`test2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_test2_test3` FOREIGN KEY (`field1`) REFERENCES `test3` (`field1`))

insert into test2 values (100, 3);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`test2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_test2_test1` FOREIGN KEY (`field1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`field1`))

insert into test2 values (100, 2);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`test2`, CONSTRAINT `fk_test2_test1` FOREIGN KEY (`field1`) REFERENCES `test1` (`field1`))
```

So...don't do that.

**Proposal**

```
create table interface_type (
  id int auto_increment, 
  type_name varchar(30), 
  primary key (id)
);

create table interface (
  id int auto_increment, 
  interface_name varchar(30), 
  interface_type int, 
  primary key (id), 
  constraint fk_interface_type 
    foreign key (interface_type) 
    references interface_type (id)
);

create table `usage` (
  id int auto_increment,
  interface_id int,
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_usage_interface
    foreign key (interface_id)
    references interface (id)
);
```

Now you can add as many types of interfaces in the `interface_type` table such as:

```
insert into interface_type (type_name) values ('physical'), ('virtual');
```

Then, add as many interfaces as you'd like in the `interface` table, and reference them in the `usage` table as needed.