# EF Core: Navigational properties to views

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to get navigational properties to work between a object that I own and maintain and a view that is controlled by a other party. Iam using a MS SQL Server database.

I have 2 models

```
public class Trajectory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //Some more data
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public List<Trajectory> Trajectories {get;set;}
}
```

The first one is a model which is created and migrate with entity. The second one is a external view which I have no control over.

So I did this in my model builder:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasNoKey()
            .ToView("SomeView");
```

And for my other entity:

```
  builder.HasOne(e => e.Contact)
            .WithMany(e => e.Trajectories)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ContactId );
```

When I ran this migration it failed with a null pointer. When I removed the HasNoKey() from the first part I got a migration. When I ran the update-database command I got the following error:

> Foreign key 'FK_Trajectories_SomeView_ContactId' references object 'SomeView' which is not a user table.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I'am kind of lost with how I can create a navigational property to the view?

Comment: Which DB are you using? Most likely it is not possible to have a foreign key to a view.

Comment: Is `Contract.Id` a possible key? You are using `HasNoKey()` but it looks like you want to use that column as a key.

Comment: Db is SQL. 
Contract.Id is actualy the key in the table where the view is generated from. But I cant add,update or delete anything from the table where it is based on(hence the view)

Comment: Then you can't have a foreign key on a view, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447122/can-i-have-a-foreign-key-referencing-a-column-in-a-view-in-sql-server

Comment: There is really is not a db called "SQL".  Do you mean "Ms-Sql-Server"?

Comment: thats what I meant indeed

Comment: When I've hit these "are (loose) children because there is not a real FK" situations..........I've had to populate the children manually, and not rely on EF to be able to figure it out for me.  #inGeneralAdvice        My code actually has names like "looseParent" and "looseChild(ren)"  so I can remember I don't have a real FK in the database or a real navigation property in my EF mapping code.